# Trying to compile a C++ code with Root (Cern) parameters included

Tags: c++, gcc, root-framework

I working on trying to compile a code written in C++ and Root on my Mac.  The code is from a colleague who works on a Linux laptop.  In addition to the different OS's, I have both a different version of gcc and Root than her and I am not sure which difference is causing the code not to compile on my machine.

She has g++ 4.8 and root 5.(something).  I have gcc 5.3.0 and root 6.06/02.

She has given to me the a line of code she uses to get her machine to compile the code

```
gcc -Wall -o executable_name code_name.cc `root-config --cflags --glibs`
```

But when I write on my machine, Terminal gives me the error

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’
```

I need help generating the correct line to get gcc to compile the code.

Comment: Have you tried using `g++` instead of `gcc`? And is your code in a file named `code_name.cc`, or should you replace that part with the actual file name?

Comment: I have, both give the same error. And, yes code is named something different and I have replaced all appropriate places with correct code.

Comment: Are you *really* using GCC? It's not the Clang alias? What output do you get from e.g. `g++ --version`?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 5.3.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: My colleague and I have been working all morning on this.  (She is more experienced than me.)  We can kind of get the code to run in Root, but no go in C++

Comment: @SarahStern What *exact* errors do you get if you run with `g++` and the *proper* path to the source file?

Comment: (what I input) gcc -Wall -o name 2016_july.cc `root-config --cflags --glibs`
(what Terminal outputs) gcc: error: 2016_july.cc: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’

g++ instead of gcc yields that same thing

Comment: @SarahStern You have to use the *correct* path to the source. Is there a file in the *current working directory* called `2016_july.cc`?

Comment: I am in the correct folder.  When I open root and run in there, it kind of works.  Originally it was supposed to work in batches, but given that I cannot run in C++, I work one file at a time.  Not gonna work when I have 10,000+ files I need to work through.

Comment: @SarahStern I have a hard time believing the path is correct if GCC says it can't find it. Can you run `file 2016_july.cc` from the same directory and show us the output?

Comment: I have been doing exactly that.  The file is in a folder called One and I navigated Terminal to that same file.

Comment: @SarahStern Could you post the output of `file 2016_july.cc`? Could it be that the file has some invisible characters in its name?

Comment: I am not sure what you mea by output.  I am unable to get the file to run so there is not output.

Comment: @SarahStern You've lost me. Is GCC now finding the file? How does one ‘*run*’ a C++ file?! As for output, `file 2016_july.cc` is a *command* that you're meant to run in your terminal as a way to check whether the file is really there. It will print output.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.  Output: `2016_july.cc: ASCII c program text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: @SarahStern And this is from the same directory in which you run GCC?

Comment: It is the same directory.

Comment: @SarahStern Then I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is two-fold: You're on OSX and you are using GCC.

The problem with this is that `root-config` assumes that since you're on OSX you will be using the OSX-standard Clang compiler which have the `-stdlib` flag. Since you're not using Clang, but GCC (which doesn't have this flag) you get an error.

You have two possible solutions: Use `clang++` instead of `g++` to compile and build (requires you to install the compiler if it's not installed already, it comes with Xcode), or to modify the `root-config` script so it doesn't add `-stdlib=libc++`. There might be environment variables or flags that the `root-config` script checks that alter the behavior, but I don't know anything about the script, you have to check it for that.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to modify the `root-config` script so it doesn't add `-stdlib=libc++`?  Given that I am trying to work with my colleague, I don't want to go away from g++.

Comment: @SarahStern GCC and Clang are mostly compatible, and as long as you're using standard C++ you could use whichever C++ compiler you want. Since your colleague seems to be using quite an old release of GCC you should not have any problems using a recent Clang. Just try using `clang++` to build instead, and see what happens.

Comment: Going to try this and see what happens

Comment: Okay this kind of did something.  ` *** Break *** segmentation violation
 Generating stack trace...
 0x000000010385fdcc in std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in name) + 4
 0x000000010385fc9d in main (in name) + 125
 0x00007fff8d2125ad in start (in libdyld.dylib) + 1`  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @SarahStern At least you can *build* the program now. The crash is a completely different issue, and if your colleague don't know what it could be then you should ask a different question about that issue (and include a full stack trace in the question body).

Comment: actually, just needed to make one very small tweak on my end and this solution actually made everything work.  Thank you!